# How to split y axis in pgfplots to display differing datasets in one graph?

Tags: pgfplots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Axis break in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots)

I'm trying to convince pgfplots to display my measurement results. It works quite well except the fact that the datasets vary in numbers. Most of them are in the same range, but one or two sets are much larger.
Is it possible to 'split' the y axis with pgfplots so that differing datasets may be displayed in the same graph?

I have created a minimal example to display what I mean:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend cell align=right,
legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,2)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,200) (1,300)};
\legend{(0,0) (1,1),(0,1) (1,2),(0,200) (1,300)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Is it possible to 'cut' the y axis after the second and resume before the third plot?

I would be glad for any hints!

Comment: OK, I searched with the wrong terms and found this later: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots?rq=1

Comment: So should we close this question if it is solved?