# axis discontinuity in bar chart

Tags: pgfplots

pgfplot provides the possibility to insert a discontinuity on the axes (see **MWE 1** & first srceenshot). However, it seems as this discontinuity is only applicable from the value 0 to `ymin`/`xmin`.

I plotted a histogram in which the occurrence of the values between -50 and -1.8 as well as between 3 and 50 are not really relevant to the reader (red boxes). However, I must provide these results. The most important part lies between the values -1.8 and 3 (green boxes). Therefore I thought in this case it would be useful just to plot the relevant part and to depict the irrelevant part with an interrupted interval (e.g. `xleft1`=-40, `xright1`=-5 and `xleft1`=5, `xright1`=40)

**Question:**

How can I insert a discontinuity as in **MWE 1** between a value `xleft` and `xrigth` in my histogram?

[image: MWE1]

[image: histograms]

**MWE 1 (example from pgfplot manual)**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=center,
    tick align=outside,
    axis x discontinuity=crunch,
    xmin=-2, enlargelimits=false
    ]

    \addplot[blue,mark=none,
         domain=-4:4,samples=20] 
        {x*x+x+104};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**MWE 2**

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}


    \begin{filecontents}{HistoData1.dat}
    x   y
    %-50    5
    -1.8    29.
    -1.6    20.
    -1.4    41.
    -1.2    43.
    -1. 44.
    -0.8    52.
    -0.6    92.
    -0.4    79.
    -0.2    80.
    0.  74.
    0.2 81.
    0.4 52.
    0.6 68.
    0.8 52.
    1.  43.
    1.2 37.
    1.4 34.
    1.6 17.
    1.8 7.
    2.  10.
    2.2 6.
    2.4 5.
    2.6 1.
    2.8 2.
    3.  2.
    %50 10
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{HistoData2.dat}
    x   y
    -50 5
    -1.8    29.
    -1.6    20.
    -1.4    41.
    -1.2    43.
    -1. 44.
    -0.8    52.
    -0.6    92.
    -0.4    79.
    -0.2    80.
    0.  74.
    0.2 81.
    0.4 52.
    0.6 68.
    0.8 52.
    1.  43.
    1.2 37.
    1.4 34.
    1.6 17.
    1.8 7.
    2.  10.
    2.2 6.
    2.4 5.
    2.6 1.
    2.8 2.
    3.  2.
    50  10
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[title={\large 1st plot}
    ]

        \addplot[title={second plot},
            ybar interval,
            fill=blue
        ] table [  
                x=x,
                y=y
        ] {HistoData2.dat} ;

        \draw[green,dashed,thick] (axis cs:-5,0) rectangle (axis cs:5,95);
        \draw[red,dashed,thick] (axis cs:-2,0) rectangle (axis cs:-52,10);
        \draw[red,dashed,thick] (axis cs:1.5,0) rectangle (axis cs:52,7.5);

        \node
        [pin=90:\scriptsize xleft1,fill=black,circle,scale=0.3] 
        (xright1) at (axis cs:-40,5) {};
        \node
        [pin=145:\scriptsize  xright1,fill=black,circle,scale=0.3] 
        (xright1) at (axis cs:-5,5) {};

        \node
        [pin=45:\scriptsize xleft2,fill=black,circle,scale=0.3] 
        (aninnernode) at (axis cs:5,2) {};
        \node
        [pin=90:\scriptsize  xright2,fill=black,circle,scale=0.3] 
        (aninnernode) at (axis cs:40,2) {};

    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[title={\large 2nd plot (relevant part of 1st plot)}
    ]

        \addplot[title={first plot},
            ybar interval,
            fill=blue
        ] table [  
                x=x,
                y=y
        ] {HistoData1.dat} ;

        \draw[green,dashed,thick] (axis cs:-2,0) rectangle (axis cs:3.3,95);

    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: PGFPlots only has builtin solution for discontinuity marks at the upper or lower range of an axis, not in-between.

Comment: That said, there may be custom solutions around on this site. This question here might be a duplicate of those questions.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Probably that one: [Axis break in pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46422)