# How do I merge an axis interval on pgfplots chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, formatting, bar-chart

I have a chart with very higher values in two columns than others, causing a very tall chart. Since I do not have any median values, I would like to 'merge' the intervals to ignore irrelevant information.

This is what I have:
[image]

I want something like this, instead:
[image]

How can I achieve it?

MWE:

```
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [scale=0.5]
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlarge x limits=0.04,
    enlarge y limits=0,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    nodes near coords style={anchor=west, rotate=90},   
    ylabel={Time (ns)},
    width=20cm, 
    symbolic x coords=
       {A,
        B,
        C,
        D,
        E,
        F,
        G,
        H,
        I,
        J,
        K,
        L,
        M,
        N,
        O,
        P,
        Q,
        R,
        S,
        T,
    },
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords, 
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    x tick label style={rotate=60,anchor=east},
    ]

    \addplot coordinates {
        (A,27.53  )
        (B,33.71  )
        (C,9238.36)
        (D,9184.26)
        (E,119.82 )
        (F,57.62  )
        (G,28.11  )
        (H,101.59 )
        (I,245.64 )
        (J,316.80 )
        (K,107.50 )
        (L,334.93 )
        (M,395.91 )
        (N,558.37 )
        (O,588.47 )
        (P,166.14 )
        (Q,183.95 )
        (R,619.40 )
        (S,95.75  )
        (T,134.50 )};

    \addplot coordinates {
        (A,79.48  )
        (B,95.78  )
        (C,9926.58)
        (D,9864.55)
        (E,314.25 )
        (F,165.87 )
        (G,58.52  )
        (H,188.77 )
        (I,188.34 )
        (J,343.45 )
        (K,196.34 )
        (L,1387.44)
        (M,1671.64)
        (N,604.58 )
        (O, 688.11)
        (P,286.23 )
        (Q,936.79 )
        (R,757.05 )
        (S,205.32 )
        (T,200.74 )};
    \legend{Option1,Option2}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can use this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88896/124842). A related, but still open question is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/380063/124842)

Comment: Almost worked. But when I try to crop the values above "2000", I'm missing the original values above "9000", althoug the layout become like I wanted. Any work around?

Comment: You have to modify the code wite something like `ymax=2000` and `restrict y to domain*=0:2015`(linked alternative solution). **Please** help us (and also you) and **add a minimal working example** ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob, check this out: is my attempt to make it work like the answer you provide.  https://pastebin.com/MdSMRL4A

Comment: I would prefer to use `ymax=1700,
restrict y to domain*=0:1850,` or `ymax=2000,
restrict y to domain*=0:2150,`(as a suggestion). But this solution is only an alternativ and do not answer your question (directly).

Comment: Nice! The only problem I'm seeing, is that the bars above the ymax limit are all aligned, giving a 'fake' look as if all of them had the same value: http://i.imgur.com/aODzJtV.png

Comment: The "problem" is the approach (here) to solve/handle the high values with `restrict y to domain*=0:<value>`.Just an alternativ. I hope we will find an optimal solution to your question correctly. Other related answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83144/124842

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not supply an MWE, I started with [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88896/124842).  There are still issues to work out, like how to put numbers on each column without duplicates.

Basically the idea is to literally merge two plots with different ranges (but the same scale). In this case I only removed the interval from 12-18, but the principle should hold for any size gap.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=top,
    scale only axis, height=4cm, ymin=18, ymax=30,% define y scale
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar=5pt,
    bar width=12pt,
    x=3cm,
    axis x line=none,
    xtick=data,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
    axis lines*=left,
    axis y discontinuity=parallel,
    ytickmin=20
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(A,2) (B,0.5) (C,10)};
\addplot coordinates {(A,20) (B,30) (C,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(A,6) (B,11) (C,7)};
\end{axis}

\draw[white,thick] (top.south east) -- (top.south west);% erase bottom edge
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\height}{4cm/(30-18)*12}% retain common scale

\begin{axis}[yshift={-\height},
    scale only axis, height={\height}, ymin=0, ymax=12,
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar=5pt,
    bar width=12pt,
    x=3cm,
    xtick=data,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
    %restrict y to domain*=0:12, % Cut values off at 12
    axis lines*=left
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(A,2) (B,0.5) (C,10)};
\addplot coordinates {(A,20) (B,30) (C,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(A,6) (B,11) (C,7)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I think I'm going with your solution. This is my resulT: http://i.imgur.com/6tRsg4p.jpg. Only thing that bothers me is the "0.9" on y axis after "1800" and 10^4, make bad to read and breake the format. There's a way to avoid this kind of notation?

Comment: Figured out using (\pgfplotsset{scaled y ticks=false}). Result: http://i.imgur.com/chyb7hN.png. Thank you all!

Comment: I would have use ytickmin=9200.  Otherwise, looks good.