# Omitting a range when plotting with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have to plot data of the following format:

```
year,value1
-10000000,10
0,10
1890,10
1900,50
1930,500
1970,1500
2000,4000
```

Using standard `pgfplots` I do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [col sep=comma,x=year,y=value1] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

From which I get this:

[image: default pgfplots plot]

The problem here is that one very small value of `-10000000`; it has to be in the plot... Is it possible to somehow omit the values from say `-9999999` to `1850`? Somehow breaking up the plot line?

I have something like this in mind? [ And I am terribly sorry for the figure! ;-) ]

[image]

Comment: Maybe something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46422/18674 may point into the right direction.

Comment: Does it have to be at -10000000? Or could it be at something like -1000?

Comment: I was unable to solve this problem in time, so I ended up creating two plots with different ranges. Nevertheless a solution for this problem would be nice.