# Multiple axis discontinuities with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to show narrow segments out of a large spectrum. Since it is one spectrum, I want to use one single plot, but hide the irrelevant parts. To make clear that I show disconnected parts, I want to use discontinued axis lines between the parts. The code example shows how far I came (based on an example from the manual):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis x discontinuity=parallel,
    axis y line=left,
    xmin=360, xmax=600,
    ymin=0, ymax=7,
    enlargelimits=false
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {
      (420,2)
      (500,6)
      (590,4)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    ymin=0, ymax=7,
    enlargelimits=false
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {
      (420,2)
      (500,6)
      (590,4)
    };

    \addplot coordinates {
      (25420,2)
      (25500,6)
      (25590,4)
    };

    \addplot coordinates {
      (50420,2)
      (50500,6)
      (50590,4)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xmin=400, xmax=1200,
    ymin=0, ymax=7,
    enlargelimits=false
    ]
    \addplot+ coordinates {
      (420,2)
      (500,6)
      (590,4)
    };
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=none,
    axis y line=none,
    xmin=25100, xmax=25900,
    ymin=0, ymax=7,
    enlargelimits=false
    ]
    \addplot+ coordinates {
      (25420,2)
      (25500,6)
      (25590,4)
    };
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=none,
    axis y line=none,
    xmin=49800, xmax=50600,
    ymin=0, ymax=7,
    enlargelimits=false
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {
      (50420,2)
      (50500,6)
      (50590,4)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code leads to these results:
[image: Discontinuity left.]
[image: Entire plot, no discontinuities.]
[image: Partial plots, discontinuities not marked,]

How can I discontinue the x axis and mark the discontinuities similar to the first plot, but between the parts?

**Edit:**

Fortunately, I was able to solve parts of the problem, but it's a very “hackish” solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.7}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    name=a,
    width=.25\linewidth,
    height=5cm,
    axis x line=box,
    axis y line*=left,
    xmin=350, xmax=750,
    ymin=0, ymax=7,
    xticklabels={,,0.4,,,0.7},
    ]
    \addplot+ coordinates {
      (420,2)
      (500,6)
      (590,4)
    };
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[
    name=b,
    width=.25\linewidth,
    height=5cm,
    xshift=2cm,
    axis x line=box,
    axis y line=none,
    xmin=25350, xmax=25750,
    ymin=0, ymax=7,
    xticklabels={,,25.4,,,25.7},
    change x base,
    x SI prefix=kilo,
    ]
    \addplot+ coordinates {
      (25420,2)
      (25500,6)
      (25590,4)
    };
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[
    name=c,
    width=.25\linewidth,
    height=5cm,
    xshift=4cm,
    axis x line=box,
    axis y line*=right,
    xmin=50350, xmax=50750,
    ymin=0, ymax=7,
    xticklabels={,,50.4,,,50.7},
    yticklabel=\empty,
    scaled x ticks=base 10:-3
    ]
    \addplot+ coordinates {
      (50420,2)
      (50500,6)
      (50590,4)
    };
  \end{axis}

  \draw [dotted] (a.south east) -- (b.south west);
  \draw [dotted] (a.north east) -- (b.north west);
  \draw [dotted] (b.south east) -- (c.south west);
  \draw [dotted] (b.north east) -- (c.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Partial solution]

With that solution, automatic scaling to `\linewidth` does not work and everything has to be done by hand, especially the line style. Is there some way to optimize and automate it?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots and the linked ones

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: I've seen the other question before, but didn't consider it being a duplicate since there are already opportunities for _one_ discontinuity in pgfplots. Now I understand better what the original discontinuity in pgfplots does and see the similarity between the questions. Anyway, thanks for the clarification that there is little chance for a better solution, especially one with only one `axis` statement. I'll try to improve my own solution and post updates here.

Comment: Is it possible to change the vertical scale between the different parts of the plot?

Comment: @joaocandre: Yes, but then you should consider additional vertical axes. Just change `ymin` and `ymax` or omit them.

Comment: Duping based on the above comments: flag if I'm wrong and I'll reopen.