# Plot not plotted with pgfplots' \nextgroupplot and discontinuities?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to do [Multiple axis discontinuities with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101024/multiple-axis-discontinuities-with-pgfplots), and so based on [Axis break in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots), I produced this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc} %\widthof

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group name=my fancy plots,
    group size=2 by 1,
    yticklabels at=edge left,
    %xticklabels at=edge bottom,
    %vertical sep=0pt,
    horizontal sep=0pt,
  },
%   width=8.5cm,
  height=6cm,
  ymin=-6, ymax=6
]

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=0,xmax=5,
  xtick={0,5,10},
  axis y line=left,
  %axis x discontinuity=parallel, % disc. is at start, so avoid for first
  axis x line=bottom,
  x axis line style=-, % switch off the axis arrow tips,
  %width=4.5cm, % don't set width,
  x=0.1cm,      % set x scale (for width)
]
\addplot {x*0};

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=45,xmax=80,
  axis y line=none,
  xtick={60,80},
  axis x discontinuity=parallel,
  axis x line=bottom,
  %width=2.0cm, % don't set width,
  x=0.1cm,      % set x scale (for width)
]
\addplot {0*x};

\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Turns out, what I get is this:

[image: test51.png]

... that is, the function is plotted only in the first "sub"plot, but not in the second one?!

Where am I going wrong, and how can I get the function to plot in its entirety?

Comment: This happens because you're evaluating the function only over the standard range `-5` to `5`. You have to set `domain=0:80`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `domain` key to your groupplots, to define within which range the function should be plotted. If this key is set in the `\begin{groupplot}` options, you don't have to play with the `sample` key, in order to get the same marker density in both parts of the plot. Of course you can also use the `no markes`key.

Applied to your MWE this would give:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc} %\widthof

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group name=my fancy plots,
    group size=2 by 1,
    yticklabels at=edge left,
    %xticklabels at=edge bottom,
    %vertical sep=0pt,
    horizontal sep=0pt,
  },
%   width=8.5cm,
  height=6cm,
  ymin=-6, ymax=6,
  domain=0:80,
]

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=0,xmax=5,
  xtick={0,5,10},
  axis y line=left,
  %axis x discontinuity=parallel, % disc. is at start, so avoid for first
  axis x line=bottom,
  x axis line style=-, % switch off the axis arrow tips,
  %width=4.5cm, % don't set width,
  x=0.1cm,      % set x scale (for width)
]
\addplot {0*x};

\nextgroupplot[
  xmin=45,xmax=80,
  axis y line=none,
  xtick={60,80},
  axis x discontinuity=parallel,
  axis x line=bottom,
  %width=2.0cm, % don't set width,
  x=0.1cm,      % set x scale (for width)
]
\addplot {0*x};

\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @ lcnittl (and @jake); I wouldn't have guessed that the `domain` setting could have been the problem. Cheers!