# How enlarge the two parts of data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Below shows the graph and code. The red circle show two portion of data. Since the upper red circle has data values >1500, therefore the lower red circle(0-500) shows all lines cramped together. Is it possible to zoom the part of lower red circle(0-500) , so the user can see more clearly the change of data? (at the same time I need to keep the upper red circle portion of data.)

[image]

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        height=6cm,
        width=7cm,
            legend pos=outer north east,
            legend pos=outer north east,
            legend style={draw=none},
             ymax=1700,
             ymin=200,
             xmin=500,
             xmax=10000,
            %xtick={0,10,20,...,50},
            scaled ticks=false,
            log ticks with fixed point={100 sep=},
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            axis line style=-,
            minor tick style={draw=none},
            ylabel = Running Time (ms),
           cycle list={
                    red,thick, dotted\\
                    black,thick, densely dotted\\
                    olive,thick,dashed\\
                    teal,thick,densely dashed\\
                    violet,thick,loosely dashed\\
                    blue,solid\\
                },
            xlabel = Running Times,
             every axis legend/.append style={xshift=-10pt}
            ]
            \addplot+[mystyle] plot  coordinates{(500,213.145126666667) (1000,243.28058) (1500,243.147242222222) (2000,239.947061666667) (2500,268.935384) (3000,275.938001111111) (3500,277.158708571429) (4000,270.282125) (4500,275.726881481481) (5000,277.582543333333) (5500,276.246103636364) (6000,278.549265) (6500,273.225883589743) (7000,274.077579047619) (7500,275.402417777778) (8000,276.811665) (8500,276.560914509804) (9000,274.323095185185) (9500,274.69641122807) (10000,278.282580333333) };
        \addplot+[mystyle] plot  coordinates{(500,203.411986666667) (1000,240.880793333333) (1500,239.125133333333) (2000,235.563816666667) (2500,260.375233333333) (3000,267.993447777778) (3500,269.558616190476) (4000,262.8903775) (4500,268.43051037037) (5000,270.589151333333) (5550,269.561213939394) (6000,271.893672222222) (6500,266.610464102564) (7000,267.501358571428) (7500,268.900168888889) (8000,270.4824825) (8500,269.898136078431) (9000,267.715658148148) (9500 ,268.082345614035) (10000,271.699219333333) };
        \addplot+[mystyle] plot  coordinates{(500,376.556006666667) (1000,412.458063333333) (1500,411.491344444444) (2000,411.37467) (2500,438.652897333333) (3000,447.015602222222) (3500,450.179274285714) (4000,443.793195) (4500,449.145354074074) (5000,451.486968666667) (5500,450.275383636364) (6000,452.593697777778) (6500,446.693359487179) (7000,447.30768047619) (7500,448.497907111111) (8000,449.589357916667) (8500,449.152323137255) (9000,447.163757407407) (9500,447.184616842105) (10000,450.81693) };
        \addplot+[mystyle] plot  coordinates{(500,463.6932) (1000,460.42634) (1500,459.781851111111) (2000,471.976995) (2500,482.760948) (3000,479.294082222222) (3500,478.23688) (4000,476.260576666667) (4500,473.715987407408) (5000,470.660256666667) (5500,469.238963030303) (6000,466.304451666667) (6500,463.334195384615) (7000,462.945528571428) (7500,462.239773777777) (8000,461.5514025) (8500,460.830282745098) (9000,459.18923) (9500,457.959530526316) (10000,457.656179)};
         \addplot+[mystyle] plot  coordinates{(500,468.160453333333) (1000,461.760086666667) (1500,458.337666666667) (2000,466.193673333333) (2500,471.347306666666) (3000,467.182622222222) (3500,466.560363809524) (4000,465.426964166667) (4500,463.145351851852) (5000,460.846700666667) (5500,459.74785030303) (6000,457.032037777778) (6500,454.292992307692) (7000,455.288287619048) (7500,454.510783555556) (8000,454.01381) (8500,453.38705882353) (9000,451.82988962963) (9500,450.664716140351) (10000,450.422772666667)};
         \addplot+[mystyle] plot  coordinates{(500,1696.64752666667) (1000,1696.71420333333) (1500,1689.89159333333) (2000,1698.13095166667) (2500,1699.96829066667) (3000,1695.20357555555) (3500,1696.08616571429) (4000,1702.98956083333) (4500,1700.36626444444) (5000,1686.04025933333) (5500,1683.2104) (6000,1679.14653111111) (6500,1669.04082564103) (7000,1668.71260095238) (7500,1670.13046044445) (8000,1668.92511333333) (8500,1667.87725882353) (9000,1665.91244074074) (9500,1664.35094842105) (10000,1663.73565033333) };
    \legend{A,B,C,D,E,F}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: logscale? (`\begin{axis}[ymode=log, ...`)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots perhaps.

Comment: This indeed begs for `semilogyaxis`

Answer (score 4):

Since `mystyle` is unavailable, I remove it to make a run. Furthermore, the data can be categorized into two category (The first A-E and the last F), two y-axis coordinates are proposed.  The y-axis for A-E is on the left whilst the y-axis for F is on the right, with y axis discontinuity feature.[image]

The basic idea is to plot A-E and then plot F. Two axes are drawn on top of each other. For more detail please check pgfplots on page 132-135.

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        scale only axis,
        height=6cm,
        width=7cm,
            legend pos=north east,
            legend style={draw=none},
             ymax=500,
             ymin=200,
             xmin=500,
             xmax=10000,
            %xtick={0,10,20,...,50},
            scaled ticks=false,
            log ticks with fixed point={100 sep=},
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            axis line style=-,
            minor tick style={draw=none},
            ylabel = Running Time (ms),
            cycle list={
                    red,thick, dotted\\
                    black,thick, densely dotted\\
                    olive,thick,dashed\\
                    teal,thick,densely dashed\\
                    violet,thick,loosely dashed\\
                    blue, solid\\
                },
             xlabel = Running Times,
           every axis legend/.append style={xshift=-10pt}
            ]
           \addplot+[] plot  coordinates{(500,213.145126666667) (1000,243.28058) (1500,243.147242222222) (2000,239.947061666667) (2500,268.935384) (3000,275.938001111111) (3500,277.158708571429) (4000,270.282125) (4500,275.726881481481) (5000,277.582543333333) (5500,276.246103636364) (6000,278.549265) (6500,273.225883589743) (7000,274.077579047619) (7500,275.402417777778) (8000,276.811665) (8500,276.560914509804) (9000,274.323095185185) (9500,274.69641122807) (10000,278.282580333333) };
        \addplot+[] plot  coordinates{(500,203.411986666667) (1000,240.880793333333) (1500,239.125133333333) (2000,235.563816666667) (2500,260.375233333333) (3000,267.993447777778) (3500,269.558616190476) (4000,262.8903775) (4500,268.43051037037) (5000,270.589151333333) (5550,269.561213939394) (6000,271.893672222222) (6500,266.610464102564) (7000,267.501358571428) (7500,268.900168888889) (8000,270.4824825) (8500,269.898136078431) (9000,267.715658148148) (9500 ,268.082345614035) (10000,271.699219333333) };
        \addplot+[] plot  coordinates{(500,376.556006666667) (1000,412.458063333333) (1500,411.491344444444) (2000,411.37467) (2500,438.652897333333) (3000,447.015602222222) (3500,450.179274285714) (4000,443.793195) (4500,449.145354074074) (5000,451.486968666667) (5500,450.275383636364) (6000,452.593697777778) (6500,446.693359487179) (7000,447.30768047619) (7500,448.497907111111) (8000,449.589357916667) (8500,449.152323137255) (9000,447.163757407407) (9500,447.184616842105) (10000,450.81693) };
        \addplot+[] plot  coordinates{(500,463.6932) (1000,460.42634) (1500,459.781851111111) (2000,471.976995) (2500,482.760948) (3000,479.294082222222) (3500,478.23688) (4000,476.260576666667) (4500,473.715987407408) (5000,470.660256666667) (5500,469.238963030303) (6000,466.304451666667) (6500,463.334195384615) (7000,462.945528571428) (7500,462.239773777777) (8000,461.5514025) (8500,460.830282745098) (9000,459.18923) (9500,457.959530526316) (10000,457.656179)};
         \addplot+[] plot  coordinates{(500,468.160453333333) (1000,461.760086666667) (1500,458.337666666667) (2000,466.193673333333) (2500,471.347306666666) (3000,467.182622222222) (3500,466.560363809524) (4000,465.426964166667) (4500,463.145351851852) (5000,460.846700666667) (5500,459.74785030303) (6000,457.032037777778) (6500,454.292992307692) (7000,455.288287619048) (7500,454.510783555556) (8000,454.01381) (8500,453.38705882353) (9000,451.82988962963) (9500,450.664716140351) (10000,450.422772666667)};
\legend{A,B,C,D,E}
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
axis y discontinuity=crunch, scale only axis,
        height=6cm,
        width=7cm,
            legend pos= south east,
            legend style={draw=none},
             ymax=1710,
             ymin=1650,
             xmin=500,
             xmax=10000,
            %xtick={0,10,20,...,50},
            scaled ticks=false,
            log ticks with fixed point={100 sep=},
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=right,
            axis line style=-,
            minor tick style={draw=none},
            ylabel = Second ordinate,
            cycle list={
                    red,thick, dotted\\
                    black,thick, densely dotted\\
                    olive,thick,dashed\\
                    teal,thick,densely dashed\\
                    violet,thick,loosely dashed\\
                    blue,solid\\
                },
            xlabel = Running Times,
            every axis legend/.append style={xshift=-10pt}
            ]
            \addplot+[] plot  coordinates{(500,1696.64752666667) (1000,1696.71420333333) (1500,1689.89159333333) (2000,1698.13095166667) (2500,1699.96829066667) (3000,1695.20357555555) (3500,1696.08616571429) (4000,1702.98956083333) (4500,1700.36626444444) (5000,1686.04025933333) (5500,1683.2104) (6000,1679.14653111111) (6500,1669.04082564103) (7000,1668.71260095238) (7500,1670.13046044445) (8000,1668.92511333333) (8500,1667.87725882353) (9000,1665.91244074074) (9500,1664.35094842105) (10000,1663.73565033333) };

\addlegendentry{F}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```