# Add break node to plot in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, labels, legend

I was able to 'break' the vertical axis using `pgfplots`, but some issues came along with it:

- Most importantly, I can't find how to add the 'break sign' (the two parallel lines) to my plot as well, and not only on the axes;
- The legend is sticking to the upper axis;
- The `ylabel` is no longer centred on the axis because I had to let it 'belong' to one of the two axes.

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{minimal}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{
    axis break gap/.initial=1mm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    name=bottom axis,   
    legend cell align=left,
    width=13cm,
    height=7.86cm,
    xlabel = {golflengte (nm)},
    ylabel = {intensiteit (arbitraire eenheden)},
    xmin = 300, xmax = 550,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 55,
    ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50},
    grid = major,
    axis x line*=bottom
]
    \addplot[no marks, color=teal!80!black, line width=0.95
]
table[x=x_ex, y=y_ex]{Eu_em_ex.txt};

\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
    at=(bottom axis.north),
    anchor=south, yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap},
    width=13cm,
    height=3.3cm,
    xmin = 300, xmax = 550,
    ymin = 85, ymax = 100,
    ytick={90,100},
    grid = major,
    legend entries = {excitatiespectrum},
    axis x line*=top,
    xticklabel=\empty,
    after end axis/.code={
         \draw (rel axis cs:0,0) +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
              ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
              +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
              (rel axis cs:1,0) +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
              ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
              +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm);
         }]
\addplot[no marks, color=teal!80!black, line width=0.95
]
table[x=x_ex, y=y_ex]{Eu_em_ex.txt};            
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The content of the file `Eu_em_ex.txt`:

```
x_em    y_em            x_ex        y_ex
500     1.73E-001       250     0.0942614858
501     1.03E-001       251     0.1122478006
502     5.22E-002       252     0.1259819159
503     1.27E-001       253     0.1244178886
504     6.10E-002       254     0.1612214076
505     1.40E-002       255     0.1334599218
506     5.82E-002       256     0.1684550342
507     1.43E-001       257     0.1643005865
508     2.24E-001       258     0.1713387097
509     5.99E-002       259     0.1960210166
510     1.33E-001       260     0.1735381232
511     5.31E-002       261     0.192844086
512     8.21E-002       262     0.2466075269
513     1.40E-001       263     0.2534501466
514     2.35E-001       264     0.2495889541
515     1.54E-001       265     0.2915244379
516     4.31E-001       266     0.3173797654
517     8.96E-001       267     0.3641539589
518     7.09E-001       268     0.4203611926
519     1.45E-001       269     0.4653269795
520     1.09E-001       270     0.5282790811
521     1.60E-001       271     0.5795987292
522     1.57E-001       272     0.6626876833
523     1.12E-001       273     0.6519349951
524     6.17E-002       274     0.7096085044
525     1.56E-001       275     0.7751021505
526     1.32E-001       276     0.7936749756
527     1.41E-001       277     0.8156691105
528     8.60E-002       278     0.9143983382
529     3.49E-002       279     0.9569203324
530     1.67E-001       280     1.0409868035
531     1.68E-001       281     0.994554741
532     1.48E-001       282     1.0927952102
533     1.27E-001       283     1.1436260997
534     2.66E-001       284     1.1265195503
535     2.32E-001       285     1.178327957
536     2.29E-001       286     1.1793054741
537     1.45E-001       287     1.2550630499
538     1.15E-001       288     1.2320913978
539     1.30E-001       289     1.1372722385
540     2.56E-001       290     1.1978782991
541     1.83E-001       291     1.2022771261
542     4.73E-001       292     1.2027658847
543     1.90E-001       293     1.1382497556
544     6.04E-002       294     1.1964120235
545     3.77E-002       295     1.1988558162
546     1.80E-001       296     1.1617101662
547     5.34E-002       297     1.1661089932
548     7.31E-002       298     1.2208499511
549     1.89E-001       299     1.7873211144
550     1.04E-001       300     1.3303318671
551     4.22E-002       301     1.1573113392
552     1.36E-001       302     1.2110747801
553     1.23E-001       303     1.4510552297
554     2.49E-001       304     2.4334599218
555     2.56E-001       305     1.6910356794
556     1.22E-001       306     1.9720718475
557     1.99E-001       307     1.9139095797
558     1.90E-001       308     1.5688460411
559     1.00E-001       309     1.4388362659
560     4.54E-002       310     1.4095107527
561     1.08E-001       311     1.3401070381
562     1.77E-001       312     1.7755909091
563     1.78E-001       313     1.4026681329
564     1.37E-001       314     1.1763729228
565     1.70E-001       315     1.1172331378
566     1.09E-001       316     1.2838998045
567     1.95E-001       317     2.0659134897
568     6.90E-002       318     2.3880053763
569     1.35E-001       319     10.0463631476
570     1.14E-001       320     2.7008108504
571     1.86E-001       321     2.6426485826
572     8.94E-002       322     2.5600483871
573     8.51E-002       323     2.5136163245
574     1.20E-001       324     1.9618079179
575     1.15E-001       325     1.2130298143
576     2.06E-001       326     1.1387385142
577     1.74E-001       327     1.5268128055
578     3.46E-001       328     2.0307228739
579     6.32E-001       329     1.5708010753
580     9.78E-001       330     0.847927175
581     2.71E-001       331     0.6841930596
582     3.08E-001       332     0.4921109482
583     4.84E-001       333     0.429012219
584     6.10E-001       334     0.358044477
585     6.67E-001       335     0.3336554252
586     9.72E-001       336     0.289471652
587     1.36E+000       337     0.2564804497
588     1.65E+000       338     0.2380542522
589     4.37E+000       339     0.1991979472
590     6.28E+000       340     0.1808206256
591     6.70E+000       341     0.1417199413
592     7.44E+000       342     0.1476339198
593     6.85E+000       343     0.1522282502
594     5.90E+000       344     0.1325801564
595     6.16E+000       345     0.1200679374
596     4.35E+000       346     0.1109281525
597     3.02E+000       347     0.1276925709
598     1.81E+000       348     0.1303807429
599     1.23E+000       349     0.2639584555
600     7.20E-001       350     0.2034012708
601     8.96E-001       351     0.3118567937
602     8.79E-001       352     0.3441637341
603     1.08E+000       353     0.2186016618
604     1.55E+000       354     0.1772526882
605     2.83E+000       355     0.2554540567
606     4.69E+000       356     0.2951412512
607     5.90E+000       357     0.4102927664
608     8.04E+000       358     0.5248577713
609     6.64E+000       359     0.5253465298
610     1.09E+001       360     0.6876143695
611     2.83E+001       361     2.9789144673
612     6.43E+001       362     15.1099017595
613     7.46E+001       363     19.7726583578
614     6.71E+001       364     1.6871256109
615     9.85E+001       365     1.4559428152
616     9.99E+001       366     2.7834110459
617     4.68E+001       367     6.0189926686
618     2.15E+001       368     3.3054051808
619     1.16E+001       369     1.4266173021
620     1.06E+001       370     0.7751021505
621     1.10E+001       371     0.8528147605
622     8.91E+000       372     1.0028636364
623     8.74E+000       373     1.994554741
624     5.53E+000       374     6.3660112414
625     3.89E+000       375     7.8127365591
626     2.54E+000       376     9.28878739
627     2.21E+000       377     16.9476339198
628     2.15E+000       378     8.1011041056
629     1.44E+000       379     7.4559428152
630     1.53E+000       380     12.0258352884
631     1.25E+000       381     14.9828245357
632     1.91E+000       382     18.2770571848
633     1.19E+000       383     15.2076534702
634     7.50E-001       384     12.1724628544
635     7.41E-001       385     16.9280835777
636     7.49E-001       386     10.7550630499
637     4.94E-001       387     7.3386407625
638     5.88E-001       388     5.0903514174
639     5.14E-001       389     3.7022771261
640     7.29E-001       390     2.5967052786
641     9.22E-001       391     2.1128343109
642     3.49E-001       392     2.6563338221
643     1.74E+000       393     5.2272038123
644     1.24E+000       394     26.380673998
645     1.51E+000       395     99.9974872923
646     7.87E-001       396     15.3933817204
647     1.17E+000       397     14.7531080156
648     6.78E-001       398     11.1607326491
649     1.21E+000       399     6.6397160313
650     1.94E+000       400     7.7443103617
651     1.46E+000       401     7.7443103617
652     1.34E+000       402     3.8611236559
653     2.48E+000       403     1.642159824
654     3.39E+000       404     0.8953367546
655     3.21E+000       405     0.7325801564
656     1.42E+000       406     0.7892761486
657     8.55E-001       407     0.6455811339
658     4.47E-001       408     0.5815537634
659     6.10E-001       409     0.4554051808
660     4.16E-001       410     0.490155914
661     2.39E-001       411     0.7804784946
662     1.39E-001       412     0.3224139785
663     2.69E-001       413     0.4706544477
664     4.25E-001       414     0.8743201369
665     2.54E-001       415     2.6289633431
666     1.62E-001       416     5.2565293255
667     4.18E-001       417     4.4388362659
668     4.35E-001       418     2.985757087
669     2.68E-001       419     1.9867346041
670     9.78E-002       420     0.6504687195
671     6.22E-002       421     0.1878587488
672     2.60E-002       422     0.0831666667
673     2.32E-001       423     0.0567248289
674     3.64E-001       424     0.0503709677
675     3.43E-001       425     0.0488069404
676     3.99E-001       426     0.142159824
677     3.11E-001       427     0.1027658847
678     6.22E-001       428     0.1928929619
679     2.91E-001       429     0.1055518084
680     6.21E-001       430     0.047927175
681     6.13E-001       431     0.0941637341
682     3.29E-001       432     0.0599995112
683     1.65E-001       433     0.0168861193
684     1.26E+000       434     0.0050239492
685     4.68E-001       435     0.0012292278
686     5.59E-001       436     0.0005733138
687     9.39E-001       437     0.0025117302
688     1.11E+000       438     0.0006959922
689     9.28E-001       439     0.0006212121
690     1.64E+000       440     0.0006510264
691     1.59E+000       441     0.0018826979
692     3.51E+000       442     0.0048675464
693     3.86E+000       443     0.0042468231
694     3.78E+000       444     0.0070327468
695     3.59E+000       445     0.0462116325
696     4.17E+000       446     0.1756886608
697     3.83E+000       447     0.1239780059
698     4.59E+000       448     0.2004687195
699     3.46E+000       449     0.251983871
700     4.35E+000       450     0.2447013685
701     1.28E+001       451     0.1481226784
702     1.60E+001       452     0.0526192571
703     9.45E+000       453     0.0310454545
704     8.06E+000       454     0.0296476051
705     4.72E+000       455     0.0568225806
706     2.54E+000       456     0.1658646139
707     1.51E+000       457     0.2763240469
708     1.08E+000       458     0.3389340176
709     8.05E-001       459     0.3150337243
710     2.61E-001       460     0.3487580645
711     3.01E-001       461     0.5101950147
712     4.50E-001       462     0.7824335288
713     1.36E+000       463     1.453987781
714     2.96E-001       464     2.6929907136
715     4.13E-001       465     53.0277903226
716     1.72E-001       466     10.0219252199
717     7.87E-002       467     2.4275948192
718     2.16E-001       468     0.8845840665
719     4.34E-001       469     0.3355615836
720     1.64E-001       470     0.3051119257
721     1.87E-001       471     0.3666466276
722     4.14E-001       472     0.627985826
723     3.08E-002       473     0.7061871945
724     3.45E-001       474     0.8904491691
725     2.02E-001       475     0.5620034213
726     3.34E-001       476     0.4044276637
727     5.54E-001       477     0.308728739
728     4.96E-001       478     0.1094618768
729     4.07E-002       479     0.0466564027
730     5.97E-001       480     0.0316026393
731     1.26E+000       481     0.039872434
732     1.83E-001       482     0.050957478
733     5.31E-001       483     0.0678685239
734     3.29E-001       484     0.0641539589
735     6.16E-001       485     0.0861480938
736     2.54E+000       486     0.2611725318
737     4.43E-001       487     0.4420620723
738     1.32E-001       488     0.1892272727
739     1.35E-001       489     0.347242913
740     3.64E-001       490     0.1708499511
741     1.16E-001       491     0.093186217
742     1.96E-001       492     0.1110747801
743     1.21E-001       493     0.0849261975
744     1.76E-001       494     0.0304100684
745     1.52E-001       495     0.0134843597
746     2.13E-002       496     0.0066368524
747     5.41E-001       497     0.0024384164
748     2.48E-002       498     0.0006911046
749     1.09E+000       499     0.0011495601
750     0.00E+000       500     0
751     2.30E-001       501     0.0025899316
752     2.92E-001       502     0.0065
753     6.24E-002       503     0.005498045
754     1.53E-001       504     0.0060014663
755     6.53E-003       505     0.0079613881
756     6.45E-001       506     0.0118372434
757     2.56E-001       507     0.0162800587
758     2.30E-001       508     0.0184941349
759     1.31E-002       509     0.0349750733
760     2.38E-001       510     0.0493445748
761     4.87E-002       511     0.0573602151
762     5.42E-001       512     0.0687482893
763     1.85E-001       513     0.0956788856
764     3.91E-001       514     0.1024726295
765     9.74E-001       515     0.1056006843
766     9.27E-002       516     0.0976827957
767     1.64E-001       517     0.0777903226
768     3.76E-001       518     0.0622478006
769     3.46E-001       519     0.04421261
770     6.00E-001       520     0.0371940371
771     3.19E-001       521     0.0490513196
772     1.05E-001       522     0.0604393939
773     1.81E-001       523     0.1042321603
774     2.97E-001       524     0.1552096774
775     3.02E-001       525     0.2929907136
776     7.82E-002       526     2.6338509286
777     4.21E-002       527     2.5483181818
778     3.20E-001       528     0.378327957
779     8.67E-002       529     0.4002243402
780     7.76E-001       530     0.5194814272
781     2.14E-001       531     0.7540855327
782     1.35E-001       532     1.3371744868
783     5.43E-002       533     3.0180151515
784     2.26E-001       534     6.9183084066
785     1.54E-002       535     10.0805762463
786     5.79E-001       536     9.0248577713
787     6.18E-002       537     6.8352194526
788     3.73E-001       538     4.8489046921
789     2.00E-001       539     4.6876143695
790     2.50E-001       540     3.0556495601
791     2.55E-001       541     1.1460698925
792     8.67E-001       542     0.5219252199
793     5.50E-001       543     0.2726583578
794     5.12E-001       544     0.1688949169
795     6.68E-001       545     0.1251510264
796     5.80E-001       546     0.0966564027
797     6.40E-001       547     0.0780835777
798     4.11E+000       548     0.0719740958
799     3.53E-001       549     0.0592663734
800     1.95E+000       550     0.0706544477
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided

Comment: Welcome at tex.sx! Your questions sounds like a near-duplicate to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots (although it is an important information for me that you have an application which does not involve bar plots).

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I have indeed read the solutions to this question as well before I posted mine, but (unlike what you would expect from the figure in the question), it is only explained how to add a break node to the axes, not the (bar) plot.

Comment: Instead of breaking the axis, would a logarithmic plot be acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work as is, but adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` (or newer) breaks it.

- To position the break sign, I first make a path along the top of the bottom axis, give both this and the plot a name with `name path=<some name>`, defined by the `intersections` library. The intersections between these two are found with `\draw [name intersections={of=topline and lowerplot,name=i}]`, which makes the coordinates `(i-1)` and `(i-2)`. A line is drawn relative to the midpoint between the those points with `($(i-1)!0.5!(i-2)$) +(-2mm,0) -- +(2mm,0)`, and similar for the second line.
- The `ylabel` is positioned manually relative to the corners of the axes.
- You can move the legend a bit downwards with `legend style={yshift=-2pt}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{
    axis break gap/.initial=1mm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    name=bottom axis,   
    legend cell align=left,
    width=13cm,
    height=7.86cm,
    xlabel = {golflengte (nm)},
    xmin = 300, xmax = 550,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 55,
    ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50},
    grid = major,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    clip mode=individual
]
    \addplot[no marks, color=teal!80!black, line width=0.95,name path=plot]
table[x=x_ex, y=y_ex]{Eu_em_ex.txt};
\path [name path=topline] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}) --
  (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
\draw [name intersections={of=topline and plot,name=i}] 
  ($(i-1)!0.5!(i-2)$) +(-2mm,0) -- +(2mm,0)
  ($(i-1)!0.5!(i-2) + (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})$) +(-2mm,0) -- +(2mm,0);
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
    at=(bottom axis.north),
    name=top axis,
    anchor=south, yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap},
    width=13cm,
    height=3.3cm,
    xmin = 300, xmax = 550,
    ymin = 85, ymax = 100,
    ytick={90,100},
    grid = major,
    legend entries = {excitatiespectrum},
    legend style={yshift=-3pt},
    axis x line*=top,
    xticklabel=\empty,
    after end axis/.code={
         \draw (rel axis cs:0,0) +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
              ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
              +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
              (rel axis cs:1,0) +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
              ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
              +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm);
         }]
\addplot[no marks, color=teal!80!black, line width=0.95]
table[x=x_ex, y=y_ex]{Eu_em_ex.txt}; 
\end{axis}
\path (bottom axis.south west -| bottom axis.outer south west) -- node[anchor=south,rotate=90]{intensiteit (arbitraire eenheden)} (top axis.north west -| top axis.outer north west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{minimal}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{
    axis break gap/.initial=0mm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    name=bottom axis,   
    legend cell align=left,
    width=14.3cm,
    height=4cm,
    xlabel = {X axis},
    xmin = 0, xmax = 10,     % Updated x-axis ranges for the bottom axis
    ymin = 38.5, ymax = 40.5,   % Updated y-axis ranges for the bottom axis
    ytick={38,39,40,41,42,43},       % Adjusted y-axis ticks
    grid = major,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    legend pos=south east,
]
\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=o,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,74.05929323)(2,74.11004875)(3,73.83395062)(4,74.1121437)(5,74.04318766)(6,74.19709055)(7,74.08991301)(8,74.14607895)(9,74.20123279)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter1}
     
\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=triangle,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,74.02102892)(7,74.01695258)(8,73.9599083)(9,73.96268008)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter2}

\addplot[
    color=green,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,74.21653139)(7,74.27160398)(8,74.34418505)(9,74.15820202)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter3}

\addplot[
    color=purple,
    mark=star,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,70.78359818)(2,70.82715427)(3,70.88941587)(4,70.86594118)(5,70.72003935)(6,73.98564562)(7,73.87784185)(8,73.81499949)(9,73.91649512)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter4}

\addplot[
    color=orange,
    mark=diamond,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,73.10161425)(7,72.99986002)(8,72.80970372)(9,72.39335599)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter5}

\addplot[
    color=brown,
    mark=asterisk,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,73.7151607)(7,73.54188442)(8,73.65497217)(9,73.67833404)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter6}

\addplot[
    color=cyan,
    mark=oplus,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,39.37007874)(2,39.37007874)(3,39.37007874)(4,39.37007874)(5,39.37007874)(6,45.5)(7,73.7824888)(8,73.72328176)(9,73.75368027)
    };
    %\addlegendentry{Parameter7}

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    at=(bottom axis.north),
    anchor=south, yshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap},
    width=14.3cm,
    height=10cm,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 10,     % Updated x-axis ranges for the top axis
    ymin = 69, ymax = 75,   % Updated y-axis ranges for the top axis
    ytick={70,71,72,73,74,80},          % Adjusted y-axis ticks
    grid = major,
    ylabel = {Y axis},
    title = {Caption},  % Added title (topic)
    title style={yshift=-1ex, text centered},  % Center the title
    %legend entries = {excitatiespectrum},
    axis x line*=top,
    legend pos=south east,
    legend cell align=left,
    xticklabel=\empty,
    after end axis/.code={
         \draw (rel axis cs:0,0) +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
              ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
              +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
              (rel axis cs:0,0) +(0mm,0mm) -- +(0mm,0mm)
              ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
              +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm);
              \draw (rel axis cs:0,0) +(-2mm,0mm) -- +(2mm,2mm)
              ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
              +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm)
              (rel axis cs:0,0) +(0mm,0mm) -- +(0mm,0mm)
              ++(0pt,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/axis break gap})
              +(-2mm,-1mm) -- +(2mm,1mm);
    }]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=o,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,74.05929323)(2,74.11004875)(3,73.83395062)(4,74.1121437)(5,74.04318766)(6,74.19709055)(7,74.08991301)(8,74.14607895)(9,74.20123279)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter1}
     
\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=triangle,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,74.02102892)(7,74.01695258)(8,73.9599083)(9,73.96268008)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter2}

\addplot[
    color=green,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,74.21653139)(7,74.27160398)(8,74.34418505)(9,74.15820202)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter3}

\addplot[
    color=purple,
    mark=star,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,70.78359818)(2,70.82715427)(3,70.88941587)(4,70.86594118)(5,70.72003935)(6,73.98564562)(7,73.87784185)(8,73.81499949)(9,73.91649512)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter4}

\addplot[
    color=orange,
    mark=diamond,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,73.10161425)(7,72.99986002)(8,72.80970372)(9,72.39335599)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter5}

\addplot[
    color=brown,
    mark=asterisk,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,73.90355191)(2,73.90355191)(3,73.90355191)(4,73.90355191)(5,73.90355191)(6,73.7151607)(7,73.54188442)(8,73.65497217)(9,73.67833404)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter6}

\addplot[
    color=cyan,
    mark=oplus,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,39.37007874)(2,39.37007874)(3,39.37007874)(4,39.37007874)(5,67.9)(6,73.91158176)(7,73.7824888)(8,73.72328176)(9,73.75368027)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Parameter7}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Then download the generated PDF file and in the original file,

```
\begin{figure*}
\center
\includegraphics[scale=0.8, trim={3cm 16.5cm 4.5cm 2.2cm},clip]{Generated_Plot1.pdf }  
% trim from right edge
%\includegraphics[trim={0 0 5cm 0},clip]{SMOTE.pdf}
\caption{\label{schema}Caption 1}\label{fig}\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Finally you can see a continuous curve.