# Axis break in pgfplots - same scaling for the two plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I've found the answer to my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots). Nevertheless I have a related question.
The MWE can be exactly the answer to the linked question, so I insert here just the "interested part" (if I have to copy the whole code, just tell me)

```
\nextgroupplot[ymin=45,ymax=80,
               ytick={60,80},
               axis x line=top, 
               axis y discontinuity=parallel,
               height=4.5cm]
\addplot {x*0};     
\addplot {x^2+50};         

\nextgroupplot[ymin=0,ymax=5,
               ytick={0},
               axis x line=bottom,
               height=2.0cm]
\addplot {x*0};     
\addplot {x^2+50};
```

There's point that is not clear to me. I read `ymin=45,ymax=80` in the first group and `ymin=0,ymax=5` in the second one so that the ratio between the two ranges is 7. As a consequence, I would have expected the two `height`s to be specified such that their ratio was exactly 7. This is not the case. Can anyone explain the reason to me? How should I chose the two `height` parameters in relation (if they are related!) to the y ranges of the two plots in order to get same unitary lenghts?

Comment: I don't see that you would necessarily always want the same unit length. That would depend entirely on the data you're plotting, and the scales they're varying on.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think if it's a diagram with a axis discontinuity then it's "necessary".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it was just **trial and error** in the cited question/answer. But I generated an **"analytic" approach**:

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
% override style for non-boxed plots
    % which is the case for both sub-plots
    every non boxed x axis/.style={} 
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group name=my fancy plots,
            group size=1 by 2,
            xticklabels at=edge bottom,
            vertical sep=0pt
                    },
        width=8.5cm,
        height=6.5cm,
        xmin=-6, 
        xmax=6,
        scale only axis = true,
        enlargelimits=false,
                    ]
        % top diagram           
        \nextgroupplot[
                        ymin=50,
                        ymax=100,
                        ytick={50,60,75,100},
                        axis x line=top, 
                        axis y discontinuity=parallel,
                        height=5cm,
                        axis y line=right,
                        ymajorgrids=true,
                       ]  
        % red line
        \addplot+[red,no markers,line width=2pt]{x^2+50};  
        % bottom diagram           
        \nextgroupplot[
                        ymin=0,
                        ymax=10,
                        ytick={0,10},
                        axis x line=bottom,
                        height=1cm
                       ]
        % blue line                    
        \addplot+[blue,no markers,line width=2pt]{x*0};           
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Proof

I also added a "proof" that the distances (the scaling, the scale) are equally in the top and bottom diagram.

[image]

### Explanation

- The important code part is `scale only axis = true` and `enlargelimits=false`. Here's a cite from the [pgfplots manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

> If `scale only axis` is enabled, `width` and `height` apply only to the axis
>   rectangle. Consequently, the resulting figure is larger that `width` and
>   `height` (because of any axis descriptions). **However, the axis box has
>   exactly the prescribed target dimensions.**

- Now you have control of the scaling.
- I chose a range of 50 to 100 in the top diagram.
- I chose a range of 0 to 10 in the bottom diagram.
- The ratio of the `height`s should be (100-50)/(10-0)=5.
- The top diagram therefore has a `height` of **5 cm** and the bottom has a `height` of **1 cm**.
- I added a proof (see second picture). The `height` for the bottom diagram is set to 1 cm (10 mm) and I measured it in Adobe Acrobat. As you can see the axis is exactly 10 mm high. In addition you can see that a delta in y of 10 is also 10 mm in both diagrams (top and bottom). This means that the scaling is the same.
- The top `axis y line` is on the `right`. Otherwise the 10 and 50 would have been overlapping.