# Shortened axis in axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

With the `axis` enviroment in TikZ, how can I make the "shortened" horisontal axis? TIA.
[image]

Comment: That's commonly called "broken axis" (this is why you couldn't find it by searching). Ther is no native possibility, but you can see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283741/axis-break-in-pgfplots-same-scaling-for-the-two-plots (in y direction) or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149081/collapse-range-in-x-axis-with-pgfplots-break-x-axis (along x)

Comment: @Rmano Given that this is at the start of the axis with no data to the left of the discontinuity, doesn't `axis x discontinuity=crunch` do exactly what the OP for?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I just discoved that option ;-) ... Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `axis x discontinuity` option (as also suggested in the comments):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    thick,
    axis lines=left,
    axis x discontinuity=crunch,
    ticks=none,
    xmin=0.8,
    xmax=2.2,
    ymin=-0.2,
    ymax=1,
]
\addplot[thick,domain=1:2] {ln(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]