# Latex pgfplots graph axis scaling

Tags: pgfplots

[image]

I have the graph to the left. I want the graph to the right, or else I can't see the difference between the two lower ones.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, height=10cm, compat=1.4, every axis/.append style={thick}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \pgfplotsset{
    scaled y ticks=false,
    scale only axis,
    legend style={at={(0,0.8)}, anchor=west, font=\tiny},
    xmin=7,
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.7, font=\Large]
    \begin{axis}[
        title=Size of search tree linear scale,
        ylabel=Nodes,
        xtick=data,
        ymin=0, 
    xlabel=xlabel ]
  \addplot[smooth,mark=square*, mark options={solid},red, dashed]
  coordinates{ (7,29788) (8,16760) (9,8770) (10,14248) (11,11456) (12,14602) (13,17456) (14,13112)
  }; \label{ie_plot} \addlegendentry{IntPairExact}
  \addplot[smooth,mark=square*, mark options={solid},blue, dotted]
  coordinates{ (7,30142) (8,16836) (9,8960) (10,14390) (11,11584) (12,14694) (13,17634) (14,13242)
  }; \label{ia_plot} \addlegendentry{IntPairApprox}
  \addplot[smooth,mark=*,mark options={solid},black]
  coordinates{ (7,256300) (8,254888) (9,144484) (10,194390) (11,135874) (12,233684) (13,243624) (14,221408)
  }; \label{int_plot} \addlegendentry{Integer}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If you have any code so far please post it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem -- the minimum code that produces the graph on the left would suffice.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.  This will also help to make sure that the solution actually works for you.

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots is a duplicate (firt hit in Google for pgfplots broken axis)

Comment: You are loading TikZ three times. And you are using a very old version of `pgfplots`. You should update your system and use `compat=1.13` then. Everything you need for your broken axis has been described in the post linked by Rmano