# Resize marker size in spy of pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to magnify a portion of a plot, but have altered line width/marker size inside the spy, so that the magnified area is not just fat lines. How is this possible with pgfplots?

Comment: Could you please provde some compilable code snippet that shows what you tried so far? This would help us help you!

Comment: You could "fake" a spy as e.g. shown at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598084/95441. By doing that you have all the freedom to do what you want.

Comment: @JasperHabicht My bad. I were so into my document that I thought this would be a lot lines for a simple question and forgot to fake a short one. Sorry...

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thank you for your suggestion. I'm trying to get it work as I am sure it would help me, but…
`! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'InsetXmin' as a floating point
 number, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'nsetXmin'..`

Comment: Got it running using the solution from comment #2. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you didn't compile the code given at the link completly, but (just) copied *some* parts of that code to *your* code. If true, then you missed to copy the part starting with `/pgf/declare function`.