# A big value on y coordinates make the other small values almost not able to shown

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In N3 i have a y value of 222000. As you can see the others are small comparing to it. So this value, makes the other bar very small. Is there a way to make this more beautiful?

This is my code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure*}[tp]
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] %[x={10.0pt},y={10.0pt}]
    \begin{axis}[
    width  = 1*\textwidth,
    height = 8cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=0.4cm,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel = {Average Load},
   xlabel = {Nodes},
    symbolic x coords={N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9,N10,N11,N12},
    xtick = data,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    enlarge x limits=0.088,
    ymin=0,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={draw=none, legend columns=-1}

]
    \addplot[style={rred,fill=rred,mark=none},postaction={pattern=north east lines}]
        coordinates {(N1, 0) (N2,0) (N3,222000) (N4,1000) (N5, 2000) (N6,10000) (N7,0) (N8,1000) (N9, 2000) (N10,3000) (N11,8000) (N12,1000)};

    \addplot[style={black,fill=black,mark=none}]
         coordinates {(N1, 20000) (N2,20000) (N3,41000) (N4, 15000) (N5, 22000) (N6,16000) (N7,20000) (N8,19000) (N9, 22000) (N10,13000) (N11,16000) (N12,21000)};
     \legend{Baseline, Load balancing protocol}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}% pic 1
\caption{\label{fig:execution:small}}
\end{figure*}
\end{center}
```

And this is what it produces:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: use `semilogyaxis` instead to make the y axis in log scale

Comment: Can you provide an example or a reference please?

Comment: Simply replace your `\begin{axis}` and `\end{axis}` with `\begin{semilogyaxis}` and `\end{semilogyaxis}`.

Comment: Also, is there a way to change the scaling on y axis manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole point of a plot is that you have a fixed scale so that people viewing the plot can easily see which bar is bigger than which other, and get a rough idea of just how different they are.  For this reason, there is no real way of showing both `222000` and `1000` on the same plot without `1000` looking small simply because `1000` is very small compared to `222000`.  So in the usual sense, what you're asking isn't really possible.

There are three alternatives I can think of:

### Omitting `N3`

Since the value for `N3` is several orders of magnitude above the rest of your data, this could indicate some sort of error or invalid outlier.  If that is indeed the case, then it would be a good idea of omit `N3` from the plot.  In fact, I would say that leaving it in is actually misleading as it implies that `N3` is of the same quality as the other data points.

### Truncating the axis

Since all the remaining values are similar and `N3` is the only value that is truly huge compared to the rest, then it is possible to truncate the *y*-axis so that the value of `N3` is off the chart (literally).

The main issue here is that you have to make it clear to the read that the value is really *off the chart* and not just coincidentally stopping at boundary of the plot.  There is also the issue that the reader can no longer visually compared how big that value is as the full bar is not shown.

Here is an example where I add an arrow to the bar to indicate that it continues, and I also explicit write the value.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=16cm,
      height=8cm,
      % plot options
      ybar,
      bar width=0.4cm,
      % x axis
      enlarge x limits=0.088,
      major x tick style = transparent,
      symbolic x coords={N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9,N10,N11,N12},
      xlabel={Nodes},
      xtick=data,
      % y axis
      ymajorgrids = true,
      ylabel={Average Load},
      scaled y ticks=false,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=50000,
      % legend
      legend cell align=left,
      legend style={
        draw=none,
        legend columns=-1
      }
    ]

    \addplot [red, fill]
      table {
        label value
        N1 0
        N2 0
        N3 222000
        N4 1000
        N5 2000
        N6 10000
        N7 0
        N8 1000
        N9 2000
        N10 3000
        N11 8000
        N12 1000
      };
    \draw [->, thick, white, xshift=-0.2cm] (N3, 47000) -- (N3, 50000)
      node [pos=0, rotate=90, anchor=east] {\(222,000\)};

    \addplot [black, fill]
      table {
        label value
        N1 20000
        N2 20000
        N3 41000
        N4 15000
        N5 22000
        N6 16000
        N7 20000
        N8 19000
        N9 22000
        N10 13000
        N11 16000
        N12 21000
      };
    \legend{Baseline, Load balancing protocol}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

### Using a Log Scale

The last alternative is to use a logarithmic scale.  This is really useful when plotting values which span many orders of magnitude, but it can have quite a few drawbacks:

- Logarithmic plots can be harder to read, and people who aren't familiar with them can have a very difficult time;
- Similar values (in this case, the black bars) will look every more similar on a logarithmic scale.  A log scale is better when all the values span many orders of magnitude;
- Bar plots don't usually have logarithmic scales (at least, not that I have seen) and with good reason because a bar that is 'twice as tall' on a logarithmic scale is no longer just 'twice the value' (which in a way is the whole point of a bar plot).

Here is the result using a logarithmic scale:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}[
      width=16cm,
      height=8cm,
      % plot options
      ybar,
      bar width=0.4cm,
      % x axis
      enlarge x limits=0.088,
      major x tick style = transparent,
      symbolic x coords={N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9,N10,N11,N12},
      xlabel={Nodes},
      xtick=data,
      % y axis
      ymajorgrids = true,
      ylabel={Average Load},
      scaled y ticks=false,
      ymin=100,
      % legend
      legend cell align=left,
      legend style={
        draw=none,
        legend columns=-1
      }
    ]

    \addplot [red, fill]
      table {
        label value
        N1 0.1
        N2 0.1
        N3 222000
        N4 1000
        N5 2000
        N6 10000
        N7 0.1
        N8 1000
        N9 2000
        N10 3000
        N11 8000
        N12 1000
      };

    \addplot [black, fill]
      table {
        label value
        N1 20000
        N2 20000
        N3 41000
        N4 15000
        N5 22000
        N6 16000
        N7 20000
        N8 19000
        N9 22000
        N10 13000
        N11 16000
        N12 21000
      };
    \legend{Baseline, Load balancing protocol}
  \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that I've had to modify the data and get rid of the `0` values as `log(0)` is undefined.

Comment: I had an error. Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `N3' (in 'N3'). Did you know how to solve this?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  Make sure that you are using the latest PGFPlots and have `compat=1.15`?  If anything, I compiled these with LuaLaTeX, but I don't think this would be it.  If all else fails, replace the `N3` x  coordinate in the `\draw` command with an actual value (it'll be between 0 and 1, corresponding to the left and right of the plot).

Comment: Yes, the overleaf that i use says to use at most compat = 1.14. You mean \draw [->, thick, white, xshift=-0.2cm] (0, 47000) -- (0, 50000) node [pos=0, rotate=90, anchor=east] {\(222000\)}; ?

Comment: I i add lets say 0.5 and 0.6 i get the error: Dimension too large.

Comment: I mean, use `\draw [...] (0.3, 47000) -- (0.3, 50000) node [...] {\(222,000\)};`, but you'll have to play around with the `x` coordinate.  `0.3` might not be correct.  You also won't need to `xshift` anymore.  I don't know what you mean by "add lets say 0.5 and 0.6".

Comment: If i add ...(0.3, 47000) -- (0.3, 50000)... i get an error: Dimension too large. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong then, at least not without seeing more code.  Are you using a log plot?  That could be the reason.  If all else fails, you could try and ask another question on this site.

Comment: No, i use exactly the first of your code. I can't solve the error :(

Comment: Ok, then try having `\draw [...] (0.3, 0.95) -- (0.3, 1) node [...] {\(222,000\)};` or `\draw [...] (axis cs: 0.3, 0.95) -- (axis cs: 0.3, 1) node [...] {\(222,000\)};`.  Perhaps it is expecting a number between 0 and 1, where `(0,0)` is the bottom left corner, and `(1,1)` is the upper right corner.

Comment: Thank you very muck.  \draw [->, thick, white, xshift=1.2cm] (axis cs: N3, 47000) -- (axis cs: N3, 50000) node [pos=0, rotate=90, anchor=east] {\(222,000\)}; is working for me

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, axis break ([this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots/62778#62778)) is a better solution. However, it is not supported in pgfplots and must be created manually.

Comment: Welcome. // Good point. Can you, or somebody else, add the required code to the posters one?