# How to remove extra vertical space when using groupplots

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots, white-space

I'm following the example from [Axis break in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots)

However, I found that you get a spurious vertical space on the plots

[image]

Any way to remove it?  And why is it there?

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.style={}}
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=my fancy plots,
        group size=1 by 2,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0pt
    },
    width=8.5cm,
    xmin=-6, xmax=6
]%
%
\nextgroupplot[ymin=45,ymax=80,
               ytick={60,80},
               axis x line=top, 
               axis y discontinuity=parallel,
               height=4.5cm]%
\addplot {x*0};%
\addplot {x^2+50};%
%
\nextgroupplot[ymin=0,ymax=5,
               ytick={0},
               axis x line=bottom,
               height=2.0cm]%
\addplot {x*0};% 
\addplot {x^2+50};%
\end{groupplot}%
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can always `\useasboundingbox` in a TikZ picture.

Comment: Aren't you overdoing it with the plots? You add them twice. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to add them only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution needed to use the repeated plots to ease further computations.  My solution was to do a work around, similar to the `\useasboundingbox` option suggested by @Henri Menke.

However, the bounding box didn't work for me out of the box.  Resetting the bounding box was needed for me with `\pgfresetboundingbox\path (plot c1r1.outer north west) rectangle (plot c1r2.outer south east);`, where the `plot` is the name of the groups and the `c1r1` is the naming convention for the group.

[image]

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.style={}}
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=plot,
        group size=1 by 2,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0pt
    },
    width=8.5cm,
    xmin=-6, xmax=6
]%
%
\nextgroupplot[ymin=45,ymax=80,
               ytick={60,80},
               axis x line=top, 
               axis y discontinuity=parallel,
               height=4.5cm,
               legend to name=leg
               ]%
\addplot {x*0};%
\addplot {x^2+50};%
\nextgroupplot[ymin=0,ymax=5,
               ytick={0},
               axis x line=bottom,
               height=2.0cm,
               legend to name=leg
               ]%
\addplot {x*0};
\addplot {x^2+50};%
\end{groupplot}%
\pgfresetboundingbox\path (plot c1r1.outer north west) rectangle (plot c1r2.outer south east); % adjust to fit
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd add these plots only once, but it may very well be that I am missing something.

```
\documentclass[convert,border=3.14mm]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.style={}}
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=my fancy plots,
        group size=1 by 2,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0pt
    },
    width=8.5cm,
    xmin=-6, xmax=6
]%
%
\nextgroupplot[ymin=45,ymax=80,
               ytick={60,80},
               axis x line=top, 
               axis y discontinuity=parallel,
               height=4.5cm]%
%\addplot {x*0};%
\addplot[red,mark=square*] {x^2+50};%
%
\nextgroupplot[ymin=0,ymax=5,overlay,
               ytick={0},
               axis x line=bottom,
               height=2cm]%
\addplot[blue,mark=*] {x*0};% 
%\addplot {x^2+50};%
\end{groupplot}%
\path(current axis.south) -- ++(0,-0.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem removing the plots is that later I will need to handle the legends some how.  I won't get all of the plots on the same legend.  As it is now, it is simulating a single plot with the discontinuity.

Comment: @adn There exist `\addlegendimage` and `\addlegendentry` for that purpose. But I can see that any of these tricks can backfire once one adds another layer of sophistication.