# How to easily add discontinuity on x-axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have this simple graph:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.pathreplacing, calc, intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-0, xmax=1000,
    ymin=0, ymax=12,
    xtick={25, 125, 250, 500, 800, 1000}, ytick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11},
    ]

    \addplot [color=black,only marks, mark=x]  coordinates {
        (25, 7.5)
        (50, 8.3)
        (100, 6.1)   
        (125, 5.2)
        (250, 8.1)
        (500, 7.7)
        (800, 9.1)
        (1000, 6.3)
        (10000, 5.5)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

All points are located relatively near on the x-axis apart from the last one. How can I easily add a jump in the x-axis such that I can show the last coordinate (100000, 5.5)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `groupplot`s, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots). For your case, the following should work:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.pathreplacing, calc, intersections, pgfplots.groupplots}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotsset{scaled x ticks=false}
    \begin{tikzpicture}    
    \begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=my fancy plots,
        group size=2 by 1,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        horizontal sep=0pt
    },
    ymin=0, ymax=12,
    ytick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11},
    height=8cm
    ]

    \nextgroupplot[xmin=0,xmax=1100,
    xtick={25, 125, 250, 500, 800, 1000},
    axis x line*=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    width=11cm]
    \addplot [color=black,only marks, mark=x]  coordinates {
        (25, 7.5)
        (50, 8.3)
        (100, 6.1)   
        (125, 5.2)
        (250, 8.1)
        (500, 7.7)
        (800, 9.1)
        (1000, 6.3)
    };

    \nextgroupplot[xmin=9900,xmax=10100,
    xtick={10000},
    axis y line=none,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis x discontinuity=parallel,
    width=4cm
    ]
    \addplot [color=black,only marks, mark=x]  coordinates {
        (10000, 5.5)
    }; 
    \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 4):

I changed the `x-axis` to logarithmic axis. Would this work for you?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.pathreplacing, calc, intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=0.1, xmax=10000,
    ymin=0, ymax=12,
    xmode=log,
    log ticks with fixed point,
   % xtick={25, 125, 250, 500, 800, 1000}, ytick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11},
    ]

    \addplot [color=black,only marks, mark=x]  coordinates {
        (25, 7.5)
        (50, 8.3)
        (100, 6.1)   
        (125, 5.2)
        (250, 8.1)
        (500, 7.7)
        (800, 9.1)
        (1000, 6.3)
        (10000, 5.5)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: or you are looking for some explicit discontinuity in your plots? in that case, we can use decorations to obtain it.

Comment: Hi, thx. In my case I cannot use a logarithmic scale.