# Stem plot with break in x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to get a stem plot in which there are a few values near the origin and a group of values far away.  I have already looked at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots).  Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group name=my fancy plots,
    group size=2 by 1,
    %xticklabels at=edge bottom,
    horizontal sep=0pt
 },
 ymin=0, ymax=1.5
  ]
  \nextgroupplot[ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
    axis lines=middle, xtick={-1,...,1},
    xticklabels={-1,...,1},
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    enlarge y limits=0.5,
    extra x tick style={
      xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex, anchor=south}},
      xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5, ytick={\empty}, yticklabels={}, 
      axis on top,
      axis line style={-Latex[round]},
      ]
    \addplot+[ycomb,black,very thick] plot coordinates
      {(-1,0) (0,1) (1,0)};
    \node[anchor=east] at (axis cs:0,1.5) {$x[n]$};

 \nextgroupplot[xmin=999, xmax=1001,
 axis lines=middle,
 hide y axis,
 ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
 xtick=1000,
 xticklabels=1000,
 axis x discontinuity=crunch,
 ]
 \addplot+[ycomb,black,very thick] plot coordinates
 {(999,0) (1000,1) (1001,0)};
 \node[anchor=south] at (axis cs:1000,1) {$1$};
 \node[anchor=north] at (axis cs:1001.5,0) {$n$};

 \end{groupplot}
 \end{tikzpicture}%
 \end{document}
```

What I am getting is not quite aligned, to say the least.  What I am looking for is for the axes to be aligned, no x-axis arrowhead for the first plots axis, joining of the two x-axes with that wavy line (to show the discontinuity) and the heights scaled correctly to match.  The spacing between the dots (at n = -1, 0, and 1 versus those at n = 999, 1000, and 1001) is also different but I require them to be equispaced.  Since I keep learning, forgetting and relearning, please excuse the naive MWE code.

[image]

Comment: you are enlarging the y limits in the one plot but not the other. Btw:  the minimal class is often too minimal for an example, better use article.

Comment: Thanks.  I am able to now align the axes.  If I can get rid of the arrowhead on the x-axis of the first plot, I'd be done, I think.  BTW, I now duplicated the first plot and merely changed the x-axis labels to what I want (i.e., 999, 1000, 1001). The spacing of these points and the y-axis scaling is now what I want.  Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ulrike pointed out, you need to adjust the y limits of the second plot. Getting rid of the arrow head is as simple as adding

```
every inner x axis line/.append style={-},
```

after `axis line stylee={-Latex[round]}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group name=my fancy plots,
    group size=2 by 1,
    %xticklabels at=edge bottom,
    horizontal sep=0pt
 },
 ymin=0, ymax=1.5
  ]
  \nextgroupplot[ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
    axis lines=middle, xtick={-1,...,1},
    xticklabels={-1,...,1},
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    enlarge y limits=0.5,
    extra x tick style={
      xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex, anchor=south}},
    xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5, ytick={\empty}, yticklabels={}, 
    axis on top,
    axis line style={-Latex[round]},
    every inner x axis line/.append style={-},
      ]
    \addplot+[ycomb,black,very thick] plot coordinates
      {(-1,0) (0,1) (1,0)};
    \node[anchor=east] at (axis cs:0,1.5) {$x[n]$};

 \nextgroupplot[xmin=999, xmax=1001,
 axis lines=middle,
 hide y axis,
 ymin=-0.5, ymax=1.5,
 xtick=1000,
 xticklabels=1000,
 axis x discontinuity=crunch,
 ]
 \addplot+[ycomb,black,very thick] plot coordinates
 {(999,0) (1000,1) (1001,0)};
 \node[anchor=south] at (axis cs:1000,1) {$1$};
 \node[anchor=north] at (axis cs:1001.5,0) {$n$};
 \end{groupplot}
 \end{tikzpicture}%
 \end{document}
```

[image]